# Control a VM qcow Golden Image networking (bonds)

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, openstack

I'm maintaining a single qcow "Golden Image" that is going to be used to test various networking configurations.
Mainly:

- 1 interface
- 2+ interfaces in different networks
- bonds

I've been searching online for the past couple of days of how to achieve it, but can't find anything concrete.
Using OpenStack to host the VMs.

My best guess is maybe create some bash scripts in the image, and call each one with `openstack server create --user-data mydata.file`. The scripts will create `ifcfg-eth*` and `ifcfg-bond0`. Is there a better way ? Can I somehow utilize `cloud-init` for that?

Comment: It's not only about the internal VM configuration (which cloud-init can handle) but also about attaching the interfaces to the VM. If your image is configured to have three NICs you'll also need three openstack interfaces attached to the instance. I don't believe that's possible during instance creation though, but I haven't tried with heat yet, maybe the orchestrator can do exactly that.

Comment: The host side (OpenStack) is already solved via automation. I'm looking on the VM side only at this time.